# Compiling tsocks-1.8 in Solaris 10 SPARC

Tags: gcc, makefile, solaris, sparc, tsocks

I have a ORACLE/Sun SPARC server with Solaris 10 SPARC OS installed
I am attempting to install tsocks-1.8beta4.tar.gz into Solaris
However in my PuTTY terminal is the following error....

```
ld: fatal: library -lc not found
```

This error is being generated by the saveme.c file within the tsocks directory. It contains the following line I believe is causing the fault

```
unlink("/etc/ld.so.preload")
```

I dont have the file ld.so.preload inside my Solaris 10 SPARC OS
What shall I do next?

Answer (score 0):

`tsocks` makes many, many Linux-specific assumptions, such as `/etc/ld.so.preload` being used, and attempting to statically link portions of the `tsocks` package.

Solaris 10 does not have a static `libc.a`.  You can not statically link any executable on Solaris 10 and later against system libraries such as `libc` and `libm`.

See [Static Linking - where did it go?](https://blogs.oracle.com/solaris/static-linking-where-did-it-go-v2):

> With Solaris 10 you can no longer build a static executable. It's not that `ld(1)` doesn't allow static linking, or using archives, it's just that `libc.a`, the archive version of `libc.so.1`, is no longer provided. This library provides the interfaces between user land and the kernel, and without this library it is rather hard to create any form of application.
>
> We've been warning users against static linking for some time now, and linking against `libc.a` has been especially problematic. Every solaris release, or update (even some patches) has resulted in some application that was built against `libc.a`, failing. The problem is that `libc` is supposed to isolate an application from the user/kernel boundary, a boundary which can undergo changes from release to release.
>
> If an application is built against `libc.a`, then any kernel interface it references is extracted from the archive and becomes a part of the application. Thus, this application can only run on a kernel that is in-sync with the kernel interfaces used. Should these interfaces change, the application is treading on shaky ground.
>
> ...

Comment: Thanks for your input Andrew. Is there anyway I can get tsocks installed on Solaris 10? I ask because even though I have successfully compiled and installed tor source code 0.2.1.21 - when I type in torify into the PuTTY terminal It says that 'tsocks' needs to be installed. If there is anyway you can help I'd be happy

Comment: @greenelephant You'd need to dig through the `tsocks` package and remove all the Linux-specific assumptions, such as trying to statically link `libc` and the `/etc/ld.so.conf` usage.

Comment: very well. Ill have to get down to business. thanks for your input! :)